# How to get data from SharedPreferences with correct way

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How to get data from `SharedPreferences` when I try I always get the result `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`.  (Token is already stored in SharedPreferences)

```
D/ViewRootImpl@22e7e79[MainActivity]( 2199): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@22e7e79[MainActivity]( 2199): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@22e7e79[MainActivity]( 2199): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@22e7e79[MainActivity]( 2199): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter ( 2199): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter ( 2199): {"data":null,"error":"Route Not Found Exception","message":"Route [login] not defined.","code":500}
```

I created a code for get my SharedPreferences data

```
class LoginProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var api = ApiServices();
  LoginModel loginModel;
  SharedPreferences preferences;

  Future<void> logout() async {
    print(getToken());
    final response = await api.client
        .post("${api.baseUrl}/logout", headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken().toString()
    });
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      clearSharePref();
      notifyListeners();
      return null;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  getToken() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = preferences.getString("token").toString();
    return token;
  }
}
```

But when I call my API (logout funtion) I fail to get my token from `SharedPreferences`.

What is the `correct way` to get my SharedPreferences data before call API?

Comment: Don't post text as image

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski done

Comment: try String s = await getToken(); then print s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just put **await** keyword to get actual data. As async function takes time to calculate so you have to wait for it to complete.

```
print(await getToken());
```

if you want to assign to any variable then follow below code.

```
var x = await getToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `Future<String>` left to getToken() method signature like below...

```
Future<String> getToken() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = preferences.getString("token").toString();
    return token;
  }
```